# Why Rmarkdown shows different random numbers in pdf output than the ones in the Rmd file?

Tags: pdf, random, r-markdown

I set.seed in Rmd file to generate random numbers, but when I knit the document I get different random numbers. Here is a screen shot for the Rmd and pdf documents side by side.
[image: Rmd and pdf side by side]

Answer (score 3):

In [R 3.6.0](https://www.r-bloggers.com/whats-new-in-r-3-6-0/) the internal algorithm used by `sample()` has changed. The default for a new session is

```
> set.seed(2345)
> sample(1:10, 5)
[1]  3  7 10  2  4
```

which is what you get in the PDF file. One can manually change to the old "Rounding" method, though:

```
> set.seed(2345, sample.kind="Rounding")
Warning message:
In set.seed(2345, sample.kind = "Rounding") :
  non-uniform 'Rounding' sampler used
> sample(1:10, 5)
[1]  2 10  6  1  3
```

You have at some point made this change in your R session, as can be seen from the output of `sessionInfo()`. You can either change this back with `RNGkind(sample.kind="Rejection")` or by starting a new R session.

BTW, in general please include code samples as text, not as images.

Comment: This was so helpful. Do you know of any issues (such as package installations) that would cause RStudio to revert back to Rounding? I was experiencing this issue all of a sudden and can guarantee that I didn't make a manual change to my RNG.

Comment: @ToddBurus I am not aware of any such issues. I would consider it a serious bug. Do you have the command history of the R session in question?

Comment: No, it's long gone. The issue first presented about a week ago and I just overlooked it. Then when I went back to figure out what was happening I tried a couple of different flushes before noticing it was an issue of generator consistency. The packages I installed around when the issue first presented were earth, RWeka, rJava, partykit, RANN and rpart.